# How to create this CSS effect?

Tags: css

I need to create a button like the one below, but it's proving exceedingly difficult to get that border effect without the use of images:

[image: see button here].

Specifically, the border effects I've seen never have a bevel effect - it's almost as though I need two borders.  The colors, shape, and other aspects of the button are not the problem here.

Here's what I have so far, which is pretty close:

```css
button {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f9fcff 0%,#93a0c6 100%);
}
```

```html
<button>OK</button>
```

Comment: Do you have an example of what you've tried so far?

Comment: I would also appreciate insight into why people are down-voting the question.

Comment: @luxdvie I just added some CSS to show you what I have so far

Comment: @David - re: insight: Gladly. Unless you tell us specifically which parts of your assignment are giving you trouble you are effectively sending us on a goose hunt. It is a little better now that we have your code, but it would be better still to tell us something like "I can achive the overall look, but the border (or whatever) is giving me trouble". You know, make it easy to answer the question and don't force the answerers to do your work for you. I sincerely hope i could help you.

Comment: @katzenhut thanks, that's a really good point.  Sorry for the vagueness of my question - I can see how that would be frustrating.  I have updated the question to make it more specific, so future readers know exactly what was causing me trouble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this effect with one element, using a [`background: linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient), double `border` and [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius).

To apply the background even to the transparent middle part of the border, increase the size of the background (i.e. `140%`) and adjust its position.

```css
button {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #8ab 100%);
  background-size: 140%;
  background-position: 0 50%;
  border: 4px double #23538a;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  color: #23538a;
}
```

```html
<button>OK</button>
```

Comment: this is perfect, thank you!!  i never thought I would see a use case for border double in a million years!

Comment: You're welcome - glad I could help! haha yes the double border normally hasn't many use case...

Answer (score 0):

This will get you close. Use a combination of `box-shadow`, `padding`, and 'border-radius`:

```
.btn-container {
  display:inline-block;
  border: solid 1px #224488;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 2px;
  background:#acd;
  box-shadow:0px 4px 6px #cde inset;
}
.btn {
  display:inline-block;
  border: solid 1px #224488;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 2px;
  background:#acd;
  box-shadow:0px 5px 10px #e0f0ff inset;
}

<div>
  <span class='btn-container'>
    <span class='btn'>Click here!</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oqqpccmf/